# Finding and changing text under logo 1.9 ce

Tags: magento-1.9, header

I have existing text under my logo in magento im having trouble finding where to edit this, under the source code its showing the text is under div class="header_content".

I tried looking in the backend but the logo img alt and welcome message does not match what my current text is. If anyone can point me in the right direction to edit this, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to know which template file you need to alter, is to enable template hinting the back office

1. Go to Magento admin panel->systems->configuration
2. Choose your store view on top left corner in Current Configuration
   Scope ex:english.
3. Go to Advanced tab. Under that click on Developer->Debug.
4. Click yes on Template path hints (phtml files).
5. Then clear cache.
6. Go to front office refresh your page and each template (block) will display its phtml file path.

[image]

happy coding

Comment: Be aware that this will put red messages all over your website - do it on a dev site ....don't do it on a live site